# Problems adding a hyphenated '-' attribute to a tag using assign in a function

Tags: javascript, dom, bootstrap-4

I'm using this function to dynamically create a user chosen number of input-groups:

```
const tag = (tag, className, props = {}) => 
    Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), {className, ...props});
```

Everything works fine except when I make a call that has a hyphenated field in it like `tag("div", "collapse", {id: "card" + cardCount, data-parent: "#parentList"}))`

It gives me an error on the 'data-parent' attribute. I replaced it with ['data-parent'] and still got an error. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add quotes around `'data-parent'`

```
tag("div", "collapse", {id: "card" + cardCount, 'data-parent': "#parentList"})
```

**P.S.**

You can find the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers)

**UPDATED**

`Object.assign()` should not be used here as its primary [purpose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is to modify objects while `document.createElement()` returns a DOM [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) which provides `setAttibute` method to add attributes to it.

So `tag` should be written as:

```
const tag = (tag, className, props = {}) => {
    const el = document.createElement(tag);
    el.className = className;
    Object.keys(props).forEach(
        key => el.setAttribute(key, props[key])
    );
    return el;
}
...

tag("div", "collapse", {id: "card" + cardCount, 'data-parent': "#parentList"})
```

Comment: I also tried that earlier, it doesn't give any errors but it doesn't assign the attribute to the div.

Comment: Updated the answer. `Object.assign` is used for objects but you are dealing with DOM element and as far as I know the only way to set data attribute is via `setAttribute` call.